# Does Elasticsearch store or not store field values by default?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

In Elasticsearch all fields of a mapping have a `stored` property which determines whether the data of the field will be stored on disk (in addition to the storing of the whole `_source`).

*It defaults to `false`.*

However each segment in every shard also has a Docvalues structure per field in the mapping. The structure stores the value of the field for all documents in the segment.

*All documents and fields are included in the structured by default.*

So on one hand, by default Elasticsearch doesn't store the values for fields. On the other hand, it does store the values in the Docvalues structure.

**So which is it?** Does Elasticsearch store or not store values by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ES stores the same field in multiple formats for different purposes.

For eg. Consider this :

```
"prop_1":{ "type":"string", "index":"not_analyzed","store":true,"doc_values":true}
```

> `prop_1` would be stored on its own as an `indexed`, `doc_values` and
>   `stored` field. On top of that the `prop_1` is stored to into the
>   `_source` field together with your other fields.

As explained above, even if `stored:false`, the field data is still persisted on disk in multiple formats.

> Stored fields are designed for optimal storage whereas doc values are
>   designed the access field values quickly. During the execution of
>   query many of doc values fields are accessed for candidate hits, so
>   the access must be fast. This the reason why you should use doc values
>   in sorting, aggregations and scrips.On the other hand stored fields should be used for return field values for the top matching documents.

Now, you can use `doc_values` to return fields in response as well :-

```
GET /_search
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "docvalue_fields" : ["test1", "test2"]
}
```

Doc value fields can work on fields that are not stored. So IMO, stored fields do not have any significance now.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I'd like to understand in what physical data structure stored fields (not doc values) are saved, and if/why this structure offers quicker fecting of single values than the doc values structure. Thanks

Comment: You may refer to : http://blog.jpountz.net/post/33247161884/efficient-compressed-stored-fields-with-lucene